# C# Code Behind Conflicting With CSS

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, webforms

I have a asp:gridview that has CSS and a OnRowDataBound event.  If I remove my OnRowDataBound event, the CSS functions just as I want, but if I leave the CSS and OnRowDataBound event then the CSS never fires.

Can someone help me with what will have both of these methods fire and function at the same time?

```
    ASP/HTML
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmps" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" OnRowDataBound="gvEmps_OnRowDataBound" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="Name"> <ItemStyle CssClass="cellOneCellPadding" Width="50%" /></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpAddress" HeaderText="Address"> <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"/></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpCity" HeaderText="City"> <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"/></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpState" HeaderText="State"> <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"/></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpZip" HeaderText="Zip"> <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"/></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpPhone" HeaderText="Phone"> <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"/></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


C# Method gvEmps_OnRowDataBound....
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    foreach (TableCell row in e.Row.Cells)
    {
        if (design1.Any(x => x == e.Row.Cells[0].Text.ToUpper())) { row.CssClass = "des1"; }
        else if (design2.Any(x => x == e.Row.Cells[0].Text)) { row.CssClass = "des2"; }
        else if (design3.Any(x => x == e.Row.Cells[0].Text)) { row.CssClass = "des3"; }
        else { row.CssClass = "defaultview"; };
    }
} 

CSS
.cellOneCellPadding {
    padding-left: 9pt !important;
}
```

Comment: Please add a [webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webforms) tag to help people identify your question.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ use that and create a demo

Comment: If you inspect the fields you expect to have a padding left of 9px do you see the class `cellOneCellPadding`? My guess is that part `row.CssClass = "des1"` etc is actually overriding the class param and you no longer have the `cellOneCellPadding` that you are defining in your css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reassigning the CssClass property in your OnRowDataBound function and overwriting the CssClass initially provided in your template. Change up your foreach to look like this:

```
foreach (TableCell row in e.Row.Cells)
{
    if (design1.Any(x => x == e.Row.Cells[0].Text.ToUpper())) { row.CssClass += " des1"; }
    else if (design2.Any(x => x == e.Row.Cells[0].Text)) { row.CssClass += " des2"; }
    else if (design3.Any(x => x == e.Row.Cells[0].Text)) { row.CssClass += " des3"; }
    else { row.CssClass += " defaultview"; };
}
```

Comment: What does adding in the += do?

Comment: @BoJackHorseman `+=` is the same as `row.CssClass = row.CssClas + " des1"`

Comment: here @BoJackHorseman take a look [+= operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator)

Comment: @BoJackHorseman Make sure to leave the space after the opening quote or you'll be appending the new class directly onto the old one and have the same problem as before.